# How much does the Repair Arm augment repair?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The Repair Arm augment has the following description:

> **Repair Arm**
>
> Repairs your hull every time you collect scrap, but reduces scrap collected by 15 percent.

Does anyone know by how much it repairs your hull?  Should I assume from the description that it repairs the hull by just one HP each time scrap is collected, or might it vary (e.g. one HP for each 10 scrap collected)?

Comment: Avoid this augmentation like the plague. Never buy it, and if you randomly loot it, sell it ASAP. It costs you insane amounts of scrap, especially in mid- to late game when scrap rewards gradually go up. Better use that scrap to repair and invest in upgrades instead, which you should anyway.

Comment: I need to double-check this, but if memory serves, repairing a point at the store costs 2 scrap. So once you're collecting more than 14 scrap you're losing money (or paying for the premium of repairing on the fly).

Comment: @AllenGould It's 2 scrap to repair in the first few sectors, and then goes up to 3 and 4 in later sectors.  Which makes the trade-off a little better in later sectors, though scrap rewards tend to go up too so perhaps it's a wash.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From personal experience (which seems backed up by [this thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/ftlgame/topics/repair_arm_constant_cost) where the developer responded), the Repair Arm heals you 1 hull point, regardless of the amount of scrap collected.

From the developer via that thread as well:

> We didn't want it to be always a positive, obvious choice. The power of constant repairs after every fight is too useful without at least a few setbacks. [...] I might sell it come sector 6 or 7 if I'm doing well since that 15% starts to hurt a lot more and the extra boost to finish off the boss is helpful.

The [FTL Wikia](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Augmentations) seems to agree with this as well:

> Repairs your hull by 1 point every time you collect scrap[.]

Answer (score 5):

Currently Wikia states "1-2 points", although I'm playing with it right now and it seems like 2 points happens most of the time (on normal).