# How do I repair my hull

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've sustained quite a bit of damage and my hull needs repairing.

The tutorial mentioned that your crew cannot repair the hull of the ship, but only subsystems.

How do I repair the hull?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will need to visit a store, which may be marked on your sector map, if you are close enough to one.  They will give you an option to repair your hull on the left side of the store panel.

You can also find/purchase hull repair drones which will heal 3 to 5 points of hull, every time you deploy it.

Other random events when traveling may also give you the chance to repair.

Comment: There's also a [Hull Repair Arm](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84973/3062) which heals 1 point every time you get scrap, but it's probably more of a penalty than a boon since it costs you 15% scrap.

Comment: Note that there is a minor exploit with Hull Repair Drones: If you have them and the Drone Recovery Arm augmentation, you can deploy the repair drone, before you want to jump away. Then, when it has repaired exactly 2 points, jump away and your drone will be recovered instead of being lost. That in effect means 2 points of hull damage repaired for free per jump, which probably means that you never have to pay for repairs again in that run.

Comment: Repair beacons (which are marked in the sectors in which they appear) will also repair you a certain amount automatically, and will provide some resources.

Comment: @hackworth nice trick

Comment: i wish they add store everytime u visit the new sector